# How to pass TypeScript enum as array with all Enums?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have method `export const getMatchPicks = (match: IMatch, ends: EndType[]): IPick[] => ends.map(end => matchToPick(match, end));`

Also, I have:

```
enum EndType {
    HOME = 'home',
    DRAW = 'draw',
    AWAY = 'away',
}
```

My goal call  `getMatchesPicksList` function passing EndType enums as array:

```
 getMatchesPicksList(matches, [EndType.HOME, EndType.AWAY, EndType.DRAW])
```

The code above has been compiled correctly. But what if I will have n length enum? How to pass it to function?

I expect something like `getMatchesPicksList(matches, EndType)` , but it returns:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof EndType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EndType[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'typeof EndType'.

Comment: so, you want a way to get all the values from a string enum?

Answer (score 1):

Well, `getMatchesPicksList()` doesn't take the `EndType` enum object directly.  It takes an array of property values of the `EndType` enum object.  It is a bit confusing that `EndType` refers to a *value* (the enum object) as well as a *type* (the string property values, something like the union `'home' | 'draw' | 'away'`).

If you want to turn a string enum object into an array of its property values, you could make a function to do it:

```
function getStringEnumValues<E extends Record<keyof E, string>>(e: E): E[keyof E][] {
  return (Object.keys(e) as (keyof E)[]).map(k => e[k]);
}
```

And then call your function on its result:

```
getMatchesPicksList(matches, getStringEnumValues(EndType));
```

If you are trying to do something else, please give more information.  Hope that helps; good luck!